# Magento REST API Errors

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I would like to create mobile app for my magento site for that I have created REST consumer and I got consumer key and consumer secrete.. Then I create rest.php file inside `rootdirectory/api/rest`. When I call `http://localhost/magento/api/rest/` on my postman getting an error like

```
{"messages": {
"error": [
  {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "oauth_problem=nonce_used"
  }
] }}
```

What I will do? I am new to magento webservices..

Comment: Maybe this question&answers helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772102/401-error-oauth-problem-nonce-used-adding-products-to-magento-w-rest-api

Comment: where I save my php file? Is it in root directory?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this PHP file and access in your browser.

```
<?php
$nonce = substr(md5(uniqid('nonce_', true)),0,16);
$temprealm="http://youmagentostore.com/api/rest/products";
$realm=urlencode($temprealm);
$oauth_version="1.0";
$oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1";
$oauth_consumer_key="ffe7ef1d24dfecdc0e5e31a438b41464R";
$oauth_access_token="gh77390c4322c9fbe58f27e409811cop";
$oauth_method="GET";
$oauth_timestamp=time();
$algo="sha1";
$key="c8e7ef1d24ffecdc0e5e31a438b4146d&8d5e6be3ee69ce8b969594aea61b7cf3"; //consumer secret & token secret //Both are used in generate signature
$data="oauth_consumer_key=".$oauth_consumer_key."&oauth_nonce=".$nonce."&oauth_signature_method=".$oauth_signature_method."&oauth_timestamp=".$oauth_timestamp."&oauth_token=".$oauth_access_token."&oauth_version=".$oauth_version;

$send_data=$oauth_method."&".$realm."&".urlencode($data);
$sign=hash_hmac($algo,$send_data,$key,1); // consumer key and token secrat used here
$fin_sign=base64_encode($sign);
$curl = curl_init();



curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Authorization : OAuth realm='.$realm.', oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_nonce="'.$nonce.'", oauth_timestamp="'.$oauth_timestamp.'", oauth_consumer_key='.$oauth_consumer_key.', oauth_token='.$oauth_access_token.', oauth_signature="'.$fin_sign.'"'));

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$temprealm);
$xml=curl_exec($curl);
```